# dorthin gehen vs hingehen

Tags: english-to-german, difference

In Michel Thomas' German Foundation Review he says:

`I want to go there`

is either:

- Ich will dorthin gehen
- Ich will hingehen

How can these two be equivalent?

What are the subtle nuances which distinguish them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's add emphasis to make it clear:

> Ich will **dort**hin gehen.
>   I want to go **there**

You point the finger to the location where you want to go. It is in contrast to going to a different location / into a different direction.

> Ich will **hin**gehen.
>   I want to **go** there

You state your decision to go there, in contrast to staying at home. "There" could either be a location or an event/activity/presentation; what exactly would have been the topic of a previous sentence.

Comment: Colloquially, gehen is often even obmitted, if you want to express your desire for attendance: Ich will/möchte hin/dahin.

Comment: @infinitezero True

Comment: that's important, because one might also say "ich will dort-**hin**-[gehen]"